# iAdd integration and requests / impressions / fill rate experience

Tags: iad

i have just integrated iAd into my app. I have strange revenue for big numbers :).

Revenue $0.58

eCPM    $0.94

Requests    3,159

Impressions 621

Fill Rate   19.66%

CTR 0.48%

Those with experience, are those numbers fine, or is my iAd integration somehow not so good. 
I just have one global banner that will be shown in 2 different screens.

thanks

Comment: Today is my first day of iAds. My fill rate is near 96% in the US and I have an eCPM of .25. It seems to me, based on what I have read, that it is a high fill rate and a low eCPM. I know that this doesn't answer your question, but I hope that someone else's statistics can still help you out a bit as you try to figure out what is happening with your own. I know that I need all the help I can get right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm expieriencing the same low revenue stats at the moment.

The cost-per-click-revenue of my iPad apps seem to be quite low since after christmas / end of december 2011. For example on Dec. 26th my app received ~ 650 impressions with a CTR of 0,4% and a revenue of 4.9 Dollars.

The revenue that apple pay you for showing / users clicking on baners in your application varies greatly depending on the actual advertisement. There's nothing you can do about that right now. Just hold on and wait til they serve ads with higher revenue again :-D

Hope that helped you ....

Fab

Comment: Helo! can i ask for a little help? i am having issues regarding integrating iAd on my app that is already live now. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894358/objective-c-implementing-iad-banner

Answer (score 1):

@Ivan, I did a quick calculation, it seems to me that the CPC is very low at ~$0.10. That's actually bit of surprise to me

Here is the equation that I created based on my understanding of the advertising model

((# of impressions * eCPM) / 1000 + (# of impressions * CTR * CPC)) * 0.6 = revenue

where 0.6 is based on the fact that Apple take 40% cut of the income.

Is there any updates of your recent numbers?

Comment: not for me and i am really getting disappointed with iAd ;( this is for last 30 days:      
Revenue eCPM Requests Impressions Fill Rate CTR
$11.66 $1.51 35,511 7,740 21.80% 0.49%

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems you're facing are

1. You have low fill rates
2. You may even want to try more than one banner. You should test Creatives to see which one performs the best and begin utilizing the banners that give you the best results.

I suggest running with an ad network that can take care of these issues for you so you can best utilize your real estate.